# How to achieve discontinuous displacement or height map?

Tags: uv, modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine, displacement, blend-modes

I am using a grayscale image to construct a height map using the displacement tool and I get something like the left image. My problem is using the left image to construct the the right one. Notice that the discs/donuts, which exist at different heights, are separated from each other and from the underlying surface. Also notice that they were smoothened out to fill the hollow space existing underneath (due to the displacement modifier).

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I very much doubt the image on the right was achieved through displacement modifier. That is simply not how displacement works, nor what it is intended for. Displacement requires a highly subdivided surface, and is most adequate for continuous smooth transitions, not hard edge abrupt steps.

Comment: The image on the left is the one generated using the displacement modifier. I want to convert it to the one on the right, do you have any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: "Convert" no, but you can start from scratch with different techniques. Use an [array modifier with an object offset](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74791/array-modifier-with-object-offset-rotate-and-scale-at-the-same-time) instead

Comment: Using curves and shrinkwrap? But this approach would be a bit faked...

Comment: Thank you @DuarteFarrajotaRamos for the comment but I need to be able to convert it not start from scratch :(

Comment: Thank you @lemon, can you elaborate?

Comment: Well... if preparing several concentric curves is in the scope here (this is the fake part I was talking about), you can shrinkwrap (modifier) them on the displaced mesh. After that add a bevel object on the curves.

Comment: Will this work for other shapes?

Comment: You can only convert between two marginally similar things, those are totally different, you can't possibly convert between the two. Why wont an array work for you if that is how to achieve the desired effect? Could you elaborate on what you are really trying to achieve?

Comment: Ahmed, no, that's why I was talking about faking the result.

Comment: The thing is the grayscale image which I am using to construct the height map can produce any terrain, I want to be able to adjust how the peaks should be separated/clipped in order to produce distinct objects (in the example the peaks turned out to be donut shaped), but this is generally not the case.

Comment: So the idea is to generate contour lines from a height map https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line#Isopleths, and give them a shape, that's it?

Comment: @lemon yes, if the shape will get me as close as possible to the right image.

Comment: Ahmed, I have never seen that with Blender... but wave me if you get an answer about that!

Comment: @lemon Will do :) Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: ... GIS addon may help: have a look http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163611/contour-lines-with-imported-shape-file-using-blender-gis-wrong-z-values and more generally, https://www.google.fr/search?q=blender+3D+contour+lines&client=firefox-b&biw=1464&bih=884&site=webhp&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwispuTRzMfSAhUnDcAKHc1aDRoQsAQIGQ

Comment: To explore https://blenderyard.wordpress.com/2014/10/17/contour-lines-as-in-maps/